# How to convert this XML to CSV using PowerShell 2.0?

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

I'm trying to convert the following XML to CSV using PowerShell 2.0, I can get some of the data out but when trying to go through the XML objects I can't seem to get just the data in a format that would allow me to make a good table.

What I have is something like this, with multiple item's

1. > ```
   > <root type="array">   
   >   <item type="object">
   >     <short_version type="string">11</short_version>
   >     <long_name type="string">Internet Explorer</long_name>
   >     <api_name type="string">internet explorer</api_name>
   >     <long_version type="string">11.0.9600.16384.</long_version>
   >     <latest_stable_version type="string"></latest_stable_version>
   >     <automation_backend type="string">webdriver</automation_backend>
   >     <os type="string">Windows 2012 R2</os>
   >   </item>
   >   ... 
   > </root>
   > ```

Either I end up with the Type or if I try and access the InnerHTML I get only the values, but in a long string.

I'm have so far:

```
[xml]$convertMe = Get-Content $jsonTemp
$convertMe.SelectNodes("//item") | % { $_.InnerText }
```

How can I get this in a nice CSV format like:

> short_version,long_name,api_name,long_version,latest_stable_version,automation_backend,os
>   11,Internet Explorer,internet explorer,11.0.9600.16384,,webdriver,Windows 2012 R2

Comment: what do you want the csv to look like?

Comment: Ideally a table where I can view the Item ChildItems in a CSV file, so the short_version, os, api_name and so on are the column headers with the values added for each item in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a hard-coded and long solution, but it works. :) Try:

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content .\test.xml)

$xml.root.item | Select-Object @(
@{l="short_version";e={$_.short_version."#text"}},
@{l="long_name";e={$_.long_name."#text"}},
@{l="api_name";e={$_.api_name."#text"}},
@{l="long_version";e={$_.long_version."#text"}},
@{l="latest_stable_version";e={$_.latest_stable_version."#text"}},
@{l="automation_backend";e={$_.automation_backend."#text"}},
@{l="os";e={$_.os."#text"}}) |
Export-Csv test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

test.csv

```
"short_version","long_name","api_name","long_version","latest_stable_version","automation_backend","os"
"11","Internet Explorer","internet explorer","11.0.9600.16384.",,"webdriver","Windows 2012 R2"
```

And alternative and probably slower solution:

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content .\test.xml)

#Foreach item
$xml.root.item | ForEach-Object {
    $obj = New-Object psobject
    $_.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
        #Get all properties/elements and values
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_.Name -Value $_.InnerText
    }
    $obj
} |
#Set property order. This also makes sure that all items exports the same properties(which a csv needs)
Select-Object short_version,long_name,api_name,long_version,latest_stable_version,automation_backend,os |
#Export to csv
Export-Csv test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: If you are going to define the properties in the Select is the second option really any more dynamic?

Comment: No, I guess not. :P `Select-Object` was added later to the second solution. It's less messy though :)

Comment: Not to put too fine a point on my own ignorance, but what's wrong with your second option without the Select portion? It looks very similar to my answer, and if my answer's no good I'd love to know why that is so I don't mis-lead people in the future.

Comment: I thought your solution was good. That's what made me write a similar, though different solution. `Select-Object` is "required" in such a solution. If not present, then the first item's properties will define the csv-header, and that may cause problems if it's missing one or more properties. :)

Comment: Oh my gosh, that totally explains what happened part way through wrapping my head around what I ended up with and had a result with 1 column, 1 value, and a bunch of nulls. Thank you, it all makes sense now.

Comment: The second option did not work for me, I kept getting errors about "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'NotePropertyName'" but the first option, not that slow, gave me exactly what I wanted.  Now I have to figure out what I missed in trying to set this up originally.  Thanks!

Comment: :) The second one didn't work because you're not running PS3.0 or later. It should be fixed now, but you should REALLY update to PS 4.0. Lots of improvements in v3/4.

Comment: I would if it was my option, I came from a PSv3/4 environment where all this was easy and going back to PSv2 I keep finding problems with things that should work but don't.  It's why much of this is harder than I remember.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a little messy but it gets you exactly what you're looking for.

```
[xml]$convertMe = Get-Content $jsonTemp
[Array]$MeConverted = $convertMe.GetElementsByTagName('item')
$Collection = @()
ForEach($Record in $MeConverted){
    $Output = new-object psobject
    $Record.selectnodes("*")|%{Add-Member -InputObject $Output -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_.Name -Value $_.'#text'}
    If($Collection){
        $T2Keys = $Collection|gm|?{$_.MemberType -match "Property"}|Select -ExpandProperty Name
        $T1Keys = $Output|gm|?{$_.MemberType -match "Property"}|Select -ExpandProperty Name
        $KeysToAdd = $T2Keys|?{$T1Keys -notcontains $_}
        $KeysToAdd|%{$Collection|Add-Member $_ ""}
    }
    $Collection += $Output
}
$Collection | Export-CSV file.csv -notype
```

**Edit:** Frode's looks a lot cleaner in my opinion, but mine does have the advantage of not having to know all of the child nodes' names.

**Edit2:** Fixed glaring flaws, obviously there will be more than one item and I totally didn't account for that. That just made my code a lot bigger because I need to account for additional potential properties. Now for each item it checks for additional properties that weren't in the collection before and adds them before adding that record to the collection.

**Edit3:** Updated the `Add-Member` command for backwards compatibility. I wasn't aware that `-NotePropertyName/Value` are v3+ until now.

Comment: I think you have a few bugs/typos. What is `$TestOut`? Also, you're missing a foreach-loop. The sample only has one item, but the real xml has multiple item-elements. :)

Comment: @FrodeF. I did indeed. I had changed variable names when I posted the answer to have them make more sense in context, and evidently missed one. Also, the multiple records thing should have been a no brainer, but obviously I need more caffeine today. Updated, and should be functional now. Thank you for pointing those issues out.

Comment: Very nice, although like Frode's option the NotePropertyName kept giving me errors, maybe it's not installed on my PSv2 machine.

Comment: I updated my script too, I wasn't aware that `NotePropertyName` and `NotePropertyValue` are v3+ syntax. You totally should update, Frode's right on that one. Lots of nice little changes since v2.

Answer (score 0):

I threw together a little PowerShell function that does this. It assumes a lot about your XML structure, but it worked with the content you posted. You'll just have to pipe it to an Out-File to get your CSV.

```
Function ConvertFrom-XMLtoCSV {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    <#
    .Synopsis
       Convert a uniform XML file to CSV with element names as headers
    .DESCRIPTION
       Takes a uniformed XML tree and converts it to CSV based on the XPath given.

       For example, assume a structure like this:
       <root>
           <item>
               <element1>Content1</element1>
               <element2>Content2</element2>
           </item>
           <item>
               <element1>Content1</element1>
               <element2>Content2</element2>
           </item>
       <root>

    .PARAMETER Path
        The path to the XML File

    .PARAMETER XPath
        The XPath query to the items that should be converted

    .EXAMPLE
       ConvertFrom-XMLtoCSV -Path .\file.xml -XPath "//item" 
    #>
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,Position=0)][String] $Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,Position=1)][String] $XPath
    )
    Begin {
        if (Test-Path $Path) {
            [XML] $XML = Get-Content $Path -Raw
        } else {
            Throw [System.IO.FileNotFoundException] "XML file was not found at the given path"
        }
        $NodeCount = $XML.SelectNodes($XPath).Count
        $FileHeaders = [System.String]::Join(",",$($XML.SelectNodes("$XPath[1]/node()") | ForEach-Object { $_.ToString()}))
        $Content = @()
    }
    Process {
        $Content += $FileHeaders
        For ($i = 1; $i -le $NodeCount; $i++) { 
            $Content += [System.String]::Join(",",$($xml.SelectNodes("$XPath[$i]/node()") | ForEach-Object {$_."#text"}))
        }

        return $Content
    }
}
```