# Issue implementing PowerShell XML to CSV solution

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

I found a solution to converting XML to CSV using PowerShell I believe is workable for my needs [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23409270/how-to-convert-this-xml-to-csv-using-powershell-2-0).

The solution example code looks like this:

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content .\test.xml)

$xml.root.item | Select-Object @(
@{l="short_version";e={$_.short_version."#text"}},
@{l="long_name";e={$_.long_name."#text"}},
@{l="api_name";e={$_.api_name."#text"}},
@{l="long_version";e={$_.long_version."#text"}},
@{l="latest_stable_version";e={$_.latest_stable_version."#text"}},
@{l="automation_backend";e={$_.automation_backend."#text"}},
@{l="os";e={$_.os."#text"}}) |
Export-Csv test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

However, after making the appropriate substitutions for my source XML, I'm merely generating a CSV with a row of headers followed by rows of commas without values.

My source XML looks like this:

```
<Report>
    <Columns>
        <Col_Name>TimeStamp</Col_Name>
        <Col_Name>MessageText</Col_Name>
        <Col_Name>EventNotificationId</Col_Name>
        <Col_Name>OperatorText</Col_Name>
        <Col_Name>TimeOfAck</Col_Name>
        <Col_Name>InitDeviceId</Col_Name>
    </Columns>
    <Record>
        <TimeStamp><![CDATA[10/1/2018 1:34:06.99 PM]]></TimeStamp>
        <MessageText><![CDATA[OnLine]]></MessageText>
        <EventNotificationId><![CDATA[Path\Text]]></EventNotificationId>
        <OperatorText><![CDATA[]]></OperatorText>
        <TimeOfAck><![CDATA[1/1/1989]]></TimeOfAck>
        <InitDeviceId><![CDATA[Path\Text]]></InitDeviceId>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        ~
    </Record>
```

(I have substituted Path\Text in a couple places for discretion.)

And my trial code with substitutions looks like this:

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content C:\Test\test.xml)

$xml.Report.Record | Select-Object @(
@{l="TimeStamp";e={$_.TimeStamp."#text"}},
@{l="MessageText";e={$_.MessageText."#text"}},
@{l="EventNotificationId";e={$_.EventNotificationId."#text"}},
@{l="OperatorText";e={$_.OperatorText."#text"}},
@{l="TimeOfAck";e={$_.TimeOfAck."#text"}},
@{l="InitDeviceId";e={$_.InitDeviceId."#text"}}) |
Export-Csv C:\Test\test.csv -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

What do I need to change to make this solution work for me?

A final thought that occurs to me now is the proprietary data type CDATA may be unreadable using my current code. If that is responsible, I'm not sure how to parse the plain text string from it. Also FWIW, I could optionally get the source data as an HTML document, but from my quick research it appears easier to script the conversion to CSV from a source XML file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xml parser will put your CDATA sections in a member called `#cdata-section`, not `#text`. So your fix is simple:

```
$xml.Report.Record | Select-Object @(
    @{l="TimeStamp";e={$_.TimeStamp."#cdata-section"}},
    @{l="MessageText";e={$_.MessageText."#cdata-section"}},
    @{l="EventNotificationId";e={$_.EventNotificationId."#cdata-section"}},
    @{l="OperatorText";e={$_.OperatorText."#cdata-section"}},
    @{l="TimeOfAck";e={$_.TimeOfAck."#cdata-section"}},
    @{l="InitDeviceId";e={$_.InitDeviceId."#cdata-section"}}) |
Export-Csv C:\Test\test.csv -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Comment: I changed my code up to `@{l="TimeStamp";e={$_.TimeStamp.![CDATA["#text"]]}}` and it appears to be running so far without errors. The source is probably thousands of lines so I'm not sure yet if it's actually working. Do you think this won't work and I should just cancel and try your method?

Comment: Disregard my above comment. I went ahead and tried your suggested changes and it worked flawlessly. Thank you!